# How to build a waterproof roof out of LEGO blocks?

Tags: building, instructions, water

How would Lego blocks be tiled to provide a water proof roof against the rain?

The lattes or internal support structure of the roof doesn't have to be also made of Lego. Basically the tiles on a roof would be replaced with lego in such a way to be waterproof where the glue holds them together but isn't the water barrier.

Comment: Hi Muze! Just to clarify, do you mean building a roof-like structure out of LEGO bricks that can offer protection against real-world rain? If so, what is the size of the roof or the area to be protected? Does it need to stay dry even in windy or stormy weather as well?

Comment: @zovits how is this? Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I have provided an answer based on my current understading of your expectations and my assumptions on your constraints and goals. If any of these does not fit, please amend the question with the appropriate details.

Comment: I'm still wondering how big of a roof you are trying to build.  Is this for a small shed or a house or a dog house or .... ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are willing to use a non-LEGO frame to hold the roof and glue to fix all together, I would recommend buying baseplates in bulk and gluing them onto a wooden frame as if they were shingles. If the gradient and the overlap (vertical between rows and horizontal between individual plates) are correctly matched, the rain won't get inside.

For more resources on professional shingle roofing see these links:

https://www.iko.com/na/pro/building-professional-tools/roofing-101/how-to-install-shingles/
https://www.wikihow.com/Lay-Shingles